# User defined well attributes

Tags: ocean

Is it possible to create and read/write user defined well attributes through Ocean? If so, how is it done? If not, any plans for upcoming releases?

By "user defined well attributes" I mean the attributes as seen in the Well attributes folder and in the Well manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can create user defined well attributes through (continous / discrete):

```
BoreholePropertyCollection.CreateProperty(Template, String);
BoreholePropertyCollection.CreateDictionaryProperty(Template, String);
```

You can then set the value of this attribute (BoreholeProperty in Ocean terms) for a well (Borehole in Ocean terms) through:

```
Borehole.PropertyAccess.SetPropertyValue(thePropertyCreatedAbove, propertyValue);
```

The Ocean created attribute would behave just like any other user attribute created from Petrel.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add string, boolean or date type attributes? What do I use as a template then?

Answer (score 1):

string and DateTime attributes are represented as DictionaryBoreholeProperties in Ocean and you can create them by specifying the type like:

```
BoreholePropertyCollection.CreateDictionaryProperty(typeof(string), "Test property");
BoreholePropertyCollection.CreateDictionaryProperty(typeof(DateTime), "Test property");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create string attributes by calling:

```
BoreholePropertyCollection.CreateDictionaryProperty(typeof(string), "My string attribute")
```

you can create bool attributes by calling:

```
BoreholePropertyCollection.CreateDictionaryProperty(typeof(bool), "My bool attribute")
```

and, you can create datetime attributes by calling:

```
BoreholePropertyCollection.CreateProperty(typeof(System.DateTime), "My date attribute")
```